# What would be the equivalent way of doing keras' "StringLookup" function in Javascript with tensorflowjs?

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I'm porting an image prediction code I have in python to node js using tensorflowjs.

The part of exporting the model for tensorflowjs to load was ok.

the prediction is being done successfully, as a result I get an array with the possibilities.

With this array in Python I would do the following:

`characters = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

characters = sorted(list(characters))

char_to_num = layers.StringLookup(
vocabulary=list(characters), mask_token=None
)

num_to_char = layers.StringLookup(
vocabulary=char_to_num.get_vocabulary(), mask_token=None, invert=True
)

`
output_text = [0]

for res in results:
res = tf.strings.reduce_join(num_to_char(res)).numpy().decode("utf-8")
output_text.append(res)

return output_text

`

My doubt is, how do I write the function
"layers.StringLookup" in nodejs with tensorflowjs or keras js ?